# Basic Ragel parser

Tags: ragel

With a machine like this:

main := (any+);

When I feed it a chunk of data, more than 1 byte, it seems to consume only 1 byte before coming out (normally) of %%write exec block. I expect it to be greedy and consume all of the provided input.

I can always check p < pe and goto to before %%write exec, but it seems to be hackish.

How do I make it "greedy" ?

Comment: The generated diagram of your machine: http://i.imgur.com/hm7C2LM.png shows that it should clearly consume all the input: there are no ways to exit the machine actually.

Comment: Isn't the double circle an acceptable termination state?

Comment: @ioquatix: It is, but it still should go up to `pe`, there is a self-referencing transition for that.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your question is missing some critical data, but the default behaviour is to consume everything up to `pe` if possible. Obviously with your machine it is possible and given Ragel 6.9 and this simple program:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

%%{
        machine main;
        alphtype char;

        main := (any+);
}%%

int main()
{
        static char data[] = "Some string!";
        int cs;
        char *p, *pe, *eof;

        %% write data;

        %% write init;
        p = data;
        pe = data + sizeof(data);
        eof = pe;

        printf("p: 0x%"PRIxPTR", pe: 0x%"PRIxPTR", eof: 0x%"PRIxPTR"\n",
               (uintptr_t) p, (uintptr_t) pe, (uintptr_t) eof);

        %% write exec;

        printf("p: 0x%"PRIxPTR", pe: 0x%"PRIxPTR", eof: 0x%"PRIxPTR"\n",
               (uintptr_t) p, (uintptr_t) pe, (uintptr_t) eof);
        return 0;
}
```

You should get something like this in the output:

```
p: 0x601038, pe: 0x601045, eof: 0x601045
p: 0x601045, pe: 0x601045, eof: 0x601045
```